# Python Relaxation for a volume potentail is not giving me expected values...?

Tags: numpy, physics

I am trying to modify an old code to solve a new problem but Im having a few problems. 
I have this code that solves the potential at any point in a region using a relaxation method.

```py
from matplotlib.pylab import *
nx=100
V=zeros((nx,nx))
V[nx-1,:]=1
err=1.0
while (err > 1e-3):
    Vold=V.copy()
    V[1:-1,1:-1]=0.25*(V[:-2,1:-1]+V[2:,1:-1]+V[1:-1,:-2]+V[1:-1,2:])
    u = (V - Vold)
    err = sqrt(sum(u*u))
imshow(V, extent=[0,1,0,1])
title('Electrostatic Potential')
colorbar()
show()
```

I am trying to solve for the potential inside the volume of a grounded cube of length 2b that has a charge Q evenly distributed over the volume of another cube (sides=2a) in the center of the larger cube. Where Q=1.5*10^-7 C, b=3m, a=1m N=40 divisions giving a length of 3/20 m per division. Since Q is distributed evenly over the center cube then p (charge density) everywhere inside the smaller cube is a constant value of Q/Vol= Q/8 C/m^3 when a=1 m. Letting p be a 3d array gives that p= Q/8 between x,y,z=(N/2-(1/3)N,N/2+(1/3)N) and p=0 everywhere else. 
The code I have so far is

```py
from matplotlib.pylab import *
N=40
b=3.0
a=1.0
e=1.256*10**-6
h=(2.0*b)/N
q=1.5*10**-7
Vol=8*a**3
V=zeros((N,N,N)) 
p=zeros((N,N,N))
V[:,:,:]=0
p[(N/2-(a*N)/b):(N/2+(a*N)/b),(N/2-(a*N)/b):(N/2+(a*N)/b),(N/2-(a*N)/b):(N/2+(a*N/b)]=q/Vol
err=1.0
while (err > 1e-3):
    Vold=V.copy()
    V[1:-1,1:-1,1:-1]=(V[:-2,1:-1,1:-1]+V[2:,1:-1,1:-1]+V[1:-1,:-2,1:-1]+V[1:-1,2:,1:-1]+V[1:-1,1:-1,:-2]+V[1:-1,1:-1,2:])/6+p[1:-1,1:-1,1:-1]*h**2/(6*e)
    u = (V - Vold)
    err = sqrt(sum(u*u))

print V[N/2,N/2,N/2]
```

But i'm not getting the expected value of V(center) ~= 1166 Volts.I instead get V(center) ~= 0.02 Volts. Is the program correct and my expected value not or is there an error in the calculation??

Comment: Please, correct the indentation, and try to keep posted code [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant.